# Is there any way to give relative path to chrome driver in jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config

Tags: jmeter, selenium-chromedriver

I want to set the chrome driver location same location as .jmx file but without hardcoding it to full path. Is there any way of achieving it ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is using the directory where the .jmx script lives as its ["base directory"](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html#getBaseDir--)

So it's sufficient to just use `chromedriver.exe` for Windows or `chromedriver` for other operating systems.

If you want to use the full path for any reason you can obtain it in the runtime using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty('file.separator'),)}chromedriver.exe
```

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: I tried with using only chromedriver.exe and also ${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir() + System.getProperty('file.separator'),)}chromedriver.exe in the path but I got below error in both cases java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is created for a ThreadGroup.

Comment: How about taking a look at [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) and figuring out the root cause of the issue? Especially pay attention to `FileServer: Default base` line - it shows where JMeter is trying to look the `chromedriver` executable when you use the relative path. For me both options are working fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjbPt.gif